# MS Test hangs when tried to execute the tests without installing visual studio

Tags: mstest

1. To execute the tests using MSTest I have already copied required dlls to specific folder.
2. It is not giving me any exception.
3. Added logging to MsTest.exe.config though no logs are generated in a file mentioned MSTest.exe.config.
4. Command is:

> C:\01Jenkins\MsTest\MSTest.exe /testcontainer:"C:\abc.dll " /resultsfile:C:abc\TestResults\testresult2.trx /category:"xyz"
>
> Loading C:\abc.dll... 
> Starting execution...

5. It gets stuck at the above point

Any type of solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to attach Visual Studio to mstest.exe (Debug>Attach To process> choose mstest.exe), pause the process and look where it get stuck

Comment: I want to execute the test on a machine where visual studio is not installed.

Comment: define "The required dlls". MsTest relies quite heavily on some of the items installed by Visual Studio and is not supported when Visual Studio or the Test Agent for Team Foundation Server are not installed.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio is this Mstest coming from? 2010, 2012, 2013?

Comment: This is the download for the Agents,  it's more lightweight than installing Visual Studio and will put everything you need in the right places for the tests to execute. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40750

Comment: I'm trying for the solution without using agents.